# Looking for C/C++ library calculating max of Gaussian curve using discrete values

Tags: c++, c, discrete-mathematics, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have some discrete values and assumption, that these values lie on a Gaussian curve.
There should be an algorithm for max-calculation using only 3 discrete values.
Do you know any library or code in C/C++ implementing this calculation?

Thank you!

P.S.:
The original task is auto-focus implementation. I move a (microscope) camera and capture the pictures in different positions. The position having most different colors should have best focus.

**EDIT**
This was long time ago :-( 
I'just wanted to remove this question, but left it respecting the good answer.

Comment: Basically, you want a *Gaussian fit*. This can be done by brutally [fitting a parabola on the logarithm of your y](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Fitting_Gaussian_Data.html); in your particular case this is very easy, since with three points you identify a single a parabola that passes through them.

Comment: Thanks. The link is unfortunatelly a Matlab implementation, but "Gaussian fit" is a goot starting point to google.

Comment: I wrote an extensive answer about your specific case, check it out. :)

Comment: What kind of microscope is this for? When you say "most different colors" are you talking about the width of a histogram? Or are you really looking at RGB camera images?

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: The microscope is composed (self made) out of different parts - none off the shelf. Currently I do really look at each pixel (only Green actually) of each 100th line of a picture. Meanwhle, we found out, that this method is not stable enough, e.g. because some (bad focus) pictures create gradients - which result s in many colors. However, The Gaussian fit will be helpfull with any other heuristics. Thank you!

Comment: The question is  embarrassing:-( Unfortunatelly, the gaussian fit didn't help our system. Math and real world couldn't agree at this point - e.g. moving microscope up and down the same number of steps didn't result in same position. What really helped was the fuzzy logic making use of many-many domain-knowledge tricks. I still wonder how it works, but no competitor could do it till now :-) [Helios](http://www.medicalexpo.com/prod/aeskudiagnostics/automatic-immunofluorescence-assay-analyzers-67515-524995.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three points that are supposed to be on a Gaussian curve; this means that they lie on the function:

[image: generic Gaussian function]

If you take the logarithm of this function, you get:

[image: log of the Gaussian function]

which is just a simple 2nd grade polynomial, i.e. a parabola with a vertical axis of simmetry:

[image: generic 2nd grade polynomial]

with

[image: coefficient definitions]

So, if you know the three coefficients of the parabola, you can derive the parameters of the Gaussian curve; incidentally, the only parameter of the Gaussian function that is of some interest to you is *b*, since it tells you where the center of the distribution, i.e. where is its maximum. It's immediate to find out that

[image: b from beta and alpha]

All that remains to do is to fit the parabola (with the "original" x and the logarithm of your values). Now, if you had more points, a polynomial fit would be involved, but, since you have just three points, the situation is really simple: there's one and only one parabola that goes through three points.

You now just have to write the equation of the parabola for each of your points and solve the system:

[image: system of the three points]

(with [image: y and z], where the *z*s are the actual values read at the corresponding x)

This can be solved by hand (with some time), with some CAS or... [looking on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717762/how-to-calculate-the-vertex-of-a-parabola-given-three-points/717791#717791) :) ; the solution thus is:

[image: solution of the parabola through three points]

So using these last equations (remember: the *y*s are the *logarithm* of your "real" values) and the other relations you can easily write a simple algebraic formula to get the parameter b of your Gaussian curve, i.e. its maximum.

[image: final result]

(I may have done some mess in the calculations, double-check them before using the results, anyhow the procedure should be correct)

(thanks at http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php for the LaTeX equations)

Comment: That system of equations is linear in alpha, beta, and gamma, so solving is VERY easy.

Comment: @Ben: feel free to add all the Gauss-Jordan steps, as much as I'm concerned I wrote enough LaTeX this night :P (I love LaTeX, but here on SO it's quite cumbersome).

Comment: Than you! Great explanation and usefull links! However, I still don't believe, that there is no available C-library doing this. I'm afraid, I will implement it myself:-(