# Interpolated center of peak (simple gaussian curve fitting)

Tags: c, curve-fitting, gaussian

I hesitate in asking this because it's a classic question and I'm sure there are plenty of solutions already but I couldn't find one after a few hours. I'm looking so a simple (*) C code do do peak detection on a 'sharp' peak of X/Y values. X is not necessarily 1,2,3... but is ordered.

(*) I think a Gaussian fit works fine, and indeed I've already implemented and tested it with GNU Scientific Library, but I'm looking for a solution **without dependencies** for embedded programming, so no GSL.

So in short if I have X={0,1,2,3} Y={0,10,10,0} the solution should be Xm=1.5. I don't care about the interpolated Ym at Xm.

The peak is 'sharp' in the sense that the highest Y (or the 2 highest Y) is many times the value of next/previous Y. That's why simply looking for the max is just not enough.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic for Stackoverflow. You may want to try over at [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @kaylum IMHO is asking for a library, not for a SW recommendation.

Comment: Erm.. from [gsl home page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) `The library is easy to compile and does not have any dependencies on other packages`. GSL doesn't not depend on anything. Or does it?

Comment: OK, then how about: Software **library** recommendations are off-topic for Stackoverflow. You may want to try over at [softwarerecs.se]. [What topics can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: Well, not looking for a library or external software, simply for code or algorithm. For instance I'll be testing the 3-point method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059942/looking-for-c-c-library-calculating-max-of-gaussian-curve-using-discrete-value tomorrow. But what if I want 5 or 11 points ?

Comment: If you fit a three-parameter quadratic equation (parabola in your link) to the the 3 (or more) data points at or near the maximum Y value, the peak of the parabola should be at the peak of the data peak for this data subset. The peak of the parabola is where the first derivative equals zero, and code for fitting a quadratic equation in C should be readily available online. This might be sufficient for your need in this case.