# Can sombody simplify this equation for me?

Tags: math, matrix, arduino, equation

I know I can use Mathematica, but sadly I dont have one. 
I just want to find the A,B,C,D
form matrix

```
| X1^3 x1^2 X1 1 |   |A|   |y0|
| X2^3 x2^2 X2 1 |   |B|   |y1|
| X3^3 x3^2 X3 1 | X |C| = |y2|
| X4^3 x4^2 X4 1 |   |D|   |y3|
```

I just want to find the simplified equations for A, B, C and D.

Actually I am trying to do a program in **arduino** that requires curve fitting using 4 points, so that I can predict the future points. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717762/how-to-calculate-the-vertex-of-a-parabola-given-three-points) , but parabola isn't accurate enough for my need.

I have already tried http://www.wolframalpha.com/.

```
linearSolve [{{(x1)^3, (x1)^2, x1, 1},
              {(x2)^3, (x2)^2, x2, 1},
              {(x3)^3, (x3)^2, x3, 1},
              {(x4)^3, (x4)^2, x4, 1}}, {{y1},{y2},{y3},{y4}}]
```

It returns a long result, which can be simplified. But, I cannot enter the full result in the search bar for simplifying (It gives me the error :Input Too Long!).

Any Ideas? Well I guess it would be possible in desktop versions.

Even after that, if the result is quite long, please substitute x1 = 0 and let me know the simplified result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Input data: arrays x[] and y[]
// x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4] - X values
// y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4] - Y values

// Calculations
A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
S1 = x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4]
S2 = x[1]*x[2] + x[1]*x[3] + x[1]*x[4] + x[2]*x[3] + x[2]*x[4] + x[3]*x[4]
S3 = x[1]*x[2]*x[3] + x[1]*x[2]*x[4] + x[1]*x[3]*x[4] + x[2]*x[3]*x[4]
for i = 1 to 4 loop
   C0 = y[i]/(((4*x[i]-3*S1)*x[i]+2*S2)*x[i]-S3)
   C1 = C0*(S1 - x[i])
   C2 = S2*C0 - C1*x[i]
   C3 = S3*C0 - C2*x[i]
   A = A + C0
   B = B - C1
   C = C + C2
   D = D - C3
end-loop

// Result: A, B, C, D
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Mathematica you can use [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

[Your equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A%20x_1%5E3%20%2B%20B%20x_1%5E2%20%2B%20C%20x_1%20%2B%20D%20%3D%20y_0%2C%20A%20x_2%5E3%20%2B%20B%20x_2%5E2%20%2B%20C%20x_2%20%2B%20D%20%3D%20y_1%2C%20A%20x_3%5E3%20%2B%20B%20x_3%5E2%20%2B%20C%20x_3%20%2B%20D%20%3D%20y_2%2C%20A%20x_4%5E3%20%2B%20B%20x_4%5E2%20%2B%20C%20x_4%20%2B%20D%20%3D%20y_3)

Comment: Thanyou for the input. Actually I had already tried that. But, it doesnt solve for A,B,C,D as you can see. I had also tried using linearSolve. It does solve, but the result is too long and there is no way I can simply it. The typing space in the search bar is smaller than the equation.
I am sorry, it doesnt work out my friend,

Comment: [Matrix inversion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+matrix+{x1^3%2Cx1^2%2Cx1%2C1}%2C{x2^3%2Cx2^2%2Cx2%2C1}%2C{x3^3%2Cx3^2%2Cx3%2C1}%2C{x4^3%2Cx4^2%2Cx4%2C1}) is the first step.